# How to get Timestamp value from sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp

I have an android app that uses Sqlite database.
I`v created Timestamp column as shown.

```
 String table   =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "  + tableNameCreated + " (" +
            GymContract.GymEntry._ID                 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            GymContract.GymEntry.COLUMN_SETS         + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            GymContract.GymEntry.COLUMN_REPS         + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            GymContract.GymEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT       + " REAL  NOT NULL, " +
            GymContract.GymEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP    + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , " +
            GymContract.GymEntry.COLUMN_MUSCLE_TYPE  + " TEXT   );";

    db.execSQL(table);
}
```

In my adapter class in BindView method,  how to get the value of timestamp column and attach it to the adapter view to be displayed to the user ?

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int      position) {

    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        return;
    }

    int id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GymContract.GymEntry._ID));
    holder.id_varAdapter.setText(String.valueOf(id));

    int sets = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GymContract.GymEntry.COLUMN_SETS));
    holder.set_varAdapter.setText(String.valueOf(sets));

    int reps = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GymContract.GymEntry.COLUMN_REPS));
    holder.rep_varAdapter.setText(String.valueOf(reps));

    double weights = mCursor.getDouble(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GymContract.GymEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT));
    holder.weight_varAdapter.setText(String.valueOf(weights));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the same as for any other value.
e.g.

```
String timestamp = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GymContract.GymEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP));
holder.timestamp_varAdapter.setText(timestamp);
```

That is assuming that you have you've setup `holder.timestamp_varAdapter` accordingly and that you want the timestamp to be in the format `2018-12-20 18:59:33` and that you have extracted the TIMESTAMP column from the table.

If you want the data to be displayed in another format you could change the query to utilise one of the date/time functions.

e.g. if you wanted just `2018-12-20` you could use `SELECT *, date(timestamp) AS mydate` for the query and then

```
String timestamp = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("mydate"));
holder.timestamp_varAdapter.setText(timestamp);
```

[Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Thank you,

I keep getting this error :
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. "

This is how i insert the value
cv.put(GymContract.GymEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, "time('now')");

Comment: That's because the the column name hasn't been found in the cursor, you need to include the TIMESTAMP column in the cursor.